# iOS5 like flipping notifiation

Tags: notifications, flip, ios5

I want to use the same effect Apple uses in iOS5 for showing new notifications (this flip-in effect). But I don't know how to start or what to google for. Could somebody please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: wait a few days (till iOS 5 is released, so we all can see what you mean). or post  a link to a video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two `CALayer`s. One aligned normally along the x and y axis, the other rotated around the x axis so that it "lies flat", i.e. its surface points down along the y axis.

Then rotate both layers by 90 degrees along the x axis. At the end of the rotation, the first layer will now "lie flat", pointing upward along the y axis and the second layer will be aligned normally along the x and y axes.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked more than a year ago, but if it's useful to you, I would checkout the new and awesome [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) css3 transitions! I would take the FlipInX effect, which looks exactly like in iOS5!

Comment: This is only helpful in a webview, as it is css3 and not objective c.

Comment: Ha! I'm going to use this in my new rails project! Awesome

Comment: Sorry @Olof , my fault... It wasn't tagged with Objective-C so I thought maybe he's building an app using PhoneGap or comparable stuff.